# C# 'dbConn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#, sql

Have the error 'dbConn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException, however VisualStudio does not pause the program and throw the exception at me. Here is the code:private void BTN_NA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (TXT_NAUN.Text != "" && TXT_NAPW.Text != "" && TXT_NAPW2.Text != "")
        {
            if (TXT_NAPW.Text == TXT_NAPW2.Text) 
            {
                string input = TXT_NAPW.Text;
                int hash = 0;
                int output = 0;
                foreach (char chara in input)
                {
                    int temp = 0;
                    temp = System.Convert.ToInt32(chara);
                    output = output + temp;
                    output = output * 2;
                }
                hash = output % 1000;
                OleDbConnection dbConn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=BHShooterProjectDB.accdb");
                string sql = "SELECT Accounts.PlayerID FROM Accounts ORDER BY Accounts.PlayerID DESC "; 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ///string comm = "SELECT Accounts.PlayerID from Accounts";
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          /// INNER JOIN Leaderboard ON Leaderboard.PlayerID = Accounts.PlayerID WHERE Accounts.PlayerUsername = @ip";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn);
                string result = "";
                dbConn.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    result = reader[0].ToString(); 
                }
                dbConn.Close();

                {
                    string comm = "INSERT INTO Accounts (PlayerUsername, PlayerPassword, PlayerID, PlayerInvID) VALUES (@NAUN, @HPW, @NAPI, @NAPI)";
                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(comm, dbConn);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAUN", TXT_NAUN.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HPW", hash);
                    foreach (char chara in result)
                    {
                        int temp = 0;
                        temp = System.Convert.ToInt32(chara);
                        result = result + temp;
                    }
                        result = result + 1;
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAPI", result);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAPI", result);
                        dbConn.Open();
                        int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); ///error appears here
                        dbConn.Close();
                    }
            }
        }

    }
```

Any suggestions on solution, have tried a lot and this is my last hope!

Thanks,

Blackclaw_

Comment: you close connection just before the insert. And your braces doesn't look good

Comment: Its a good practice to use `using` commands specially for db connections something like `using (OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection()){ }` check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx#adonetbest_topic4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the line you got the error, you are using cmd (the select command).  I think you want to use command (the insert command).

Comment: Yeah...... i see that now, sorry im new to programming and C#, im gonna split them into different procedures and then just call the procedures so i cant make that mistake again. I spent 2 hours just running through the program trying to see where it was tripping up, cant believe i didn't see that. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Also: OleDb with Access uses positional parameters marked with a `?` character, rather than named parameter like `@name`.